# Sum absolute difference of consecutive numbers in integer

Tags: python

How can I get every digit of an integer without lists or string?

```
n = int(input())
if n < 10:
    print(n)
else:
    while n > 0:
        num = n % 10
        n //= 10
        sum = abs(num)
        print(sum)
```

Here is my assignment

[image]

I don't get how can I store every number of an integer without lists or strings like 2735 a= 2, b = 7, c = 3, d = 5 and then do this formula with absolute values. I know how to get every digit but not how to store it for later.

Comment: What is the problem with your current approach?  I think you've started down a good path...just need to finish it.

Comment: Please explain what you expect `abs(num)` to do when the instructions mentioned to get the difference of two digits at a time

Comment: I don't get how can i store every number of an integer without lists or strings like 2735 a= 2, b = 7, c = 3, d = 5 and than do this formula with absolute values

Comment: I know how to get every digit but not how to store it for later

Comment: or there is another way how to do this task

Comment: Don't think of a, b, c, d... You need to look at the number in reverse. e.g. `abs((273 % 10) - (2735 % 10))` = `abs(3 - 5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code and tell me if it works for you:

```
a = int(input())
 
last = -1
ans = 0
if a < 10:
    print(a)
else:
    while (a != 0):
        cur = a % 10
        if (last != -1):
            ans += abs(last - cur)
        last = cur
        a //= 10
    print(ans)
```

Comment: it works, now it is clear to me, many thanks

Comment: Happy to help and don't forget to mark my answer)

Answer (score 0):

To get the one's digit you can modulo 10 the value so 423%10=3

for the 10s digit /= the original number by 10 and again modulo by 10 you now have the 10s digit.

You can repeat this divide modulo pattern to get all the numbers at each place.

Comment: OP appears to already understand that logic

Comment: yeah i know that but don't know how to store that values without lists or strings

Comment: @Ole Start with `adder = 0`. Then `num = n % 10` already "stores" `num`. You don't need to store **every** number, only two at a time. Then aggregate to a `adder += abs(num1 - num2)`

Answer (score 0):

You already understand that `% 10` will store the right-most digit and `// 10` will remove it.

So, with those operations, use them *multiple times* to get two digits. You could also use Python's built-in `divmod()` to do both at the same time.

As an example, do the algorithm by-hand... I'll leave the loop conversion up to you

```
adder = 0

n = 82571

n, num1 = divmod(n, 10) # (8257, 1)
# TODO: check n == 0
num2 = n % 10 # 7
adder += abs(num2 - num1) # abs(7 - 1) == 6 ; adder = 6

n, num1 = divmod(n, 10) # (825, 7)
# TODO: check n == 0
num2 = n % 10 # 5
adder += abs(num2 - num1) # abs(5 - 7) == 2 ; adder = 8

n, num1 = divmod(n, 10) # (82, 5)
# TODO: check n == 0
num2 = n % 10 # 2
adder += abs(num2 - num1) # abs(2 - 5) == 3 ; adder = 11

n, num1 = divmod(n, 10) # (8, 2)
# TODO: check n == 0
num2 = n % 10 # 8
adder += abs(num2 - num1) # abs(8 - 2) == 6 ; adder = 17

n, num1 = divmod(n, 10) # (0, 8)
# n == 0 ... return adder = 17
```

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this iteratively by getting the difference between the last two digits and repeating the operation on the number without its last digit.

```
def diffDigits(N):
    if N<10: return N                # single digit number
    result = 0
    while N>9:
        result += abs(N//10%10-N%10) # difference between last two digits
        N = N//10                    # remove last digit
    return result

print(diffDigits(82571)) # 17
```

Or recursively (using a flag for the single digit exception):

```
def diffDigits(N,sd=1):
    return N*sd if N<10 else abs(N//10%10-N%10)+diffDigits(N//10,0)
```

Another approach is to create an iterator that will return the digits of a number and use zip() and sum() to add the differences:

```
def digits(N):
    yield N%10
    if N>9: yield from digits(N//10)

n = int(input("number: "))
print(sum(abs(a-b) for a,b in zip(digits(n),digits(n//10))))
```